# How to call a value of an object in a list by using string

Tags: python, string, list, variables

I want to call a value of an object stored in a list:

List is: `circles #storing 40 circle objects`

The object is: a circle storing values #direction in x and y

Now i want to call `circles[0].dirnx` but `dirnx` is a string called `whichDir`

In Code:

```
whichCircle = 0
whichSpeed = 1
whichDir = 'dirnx' # dirnx = direction in x
dots[whichCircle].whichDir = whichSpeed
```

Of course python creates `dots[whichCircle].whichDir` and stores `whichSpeed`
but i want to store in `dots[whichCircle].dirnx`

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the special variable `__dict__` should achieve what you want:

```
dots[whichCircle].__dict__[whichDir] = whichSpeed
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find an item with a specific value in a list, you can do the following:

```
list_name.index('dirnx')
```

This will return the index of the position in the list.